# Workaround for known timestamp bug of *.nocache.js files (for Windows / without Maven)

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.7

In GWT 2.7 there is the already known bug with *.nocache.js files, which are not getting the actual timestamp while compiling but the timestamp of the module file (see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/iqTXokgMiac)).

For the gwt-maven-plugin there was already a workaround commited ([see CompileMojo.java](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin/blob/1.0-rc-6/src/main/java/net/ltgt/gwt/maven/CompileMojo.java#L229-L234)).

**For those projects which are not built with Maven I wanted to ask, if someone knows a "maven-free" and automated solution as workaround?!**

What I'm doing right know is touching the file on my Linux server with

```
find /my/path/ -name '*.nocache.js' -exec touch {} \; &&
```

which is working fine right now. I can also use `copy /b filename.ext +,,` on Windows, but I wanted to know if someone knows an automated workaround for this compilation issue in GWT 2.7 (with Eclipse)

Comment: I'm sorry, but why you don't want to use maven? The maven is a good automation solution.

Comment: Well that's true but I have a project which is no Maven project and I can't change it at the moment. For my Maven projects I don't have any problems :)

Comment: You could add a parameter to your request : .nocache.js?dummyParam=${new Date()}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install the "touch" command on windows and keep using your current script.

You can find a number of implementations of touch for windows, here an open source one:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/touchforwindows/